# Placing images over a US map in R - receiving coercion failure

Tags: r, loops, ggplot2, maps, spatial

Current Code:

```
        library(USAboundaries)
#install.packages("USAboundariesData", repos = "https://ropensci.r-universe.dev", type = "source")
    library(sf)
    #> Linking to GEOS 3.9.1, GDAL 3.2.1, PROJ 7.2.1; sf_use_s2() is TRUE
    library(tidyverse)
    library(rasterpic)
    library(tidyterra)
    
    states <- USAboundaries::states_contemporary_lores %>%
      select(State = state_abbr) %>%
      filter(!(State %in% c("AK", "HI", "PR"))) %>%
      st_transform("ESRI:102003") 
    
    states

    plot <- ggplot(states) +
      geom_sf(fill = "white") +
      theme_minimal() +
      theme(panel.background = element_rect(fill = "lightblue1"))
    
    plot
   
    teams <- data.frame(State = January$ShipState)
    teams$Team <- data.frame(Team = January$Team)
   
    logos <- teams %>%
      rowwise() %>%
      mutate(png = switch(Team$Team,
                          "Kansas City Chiefs" = "https://cdn.freebiesupply.com/images/large/2x/kansas-city-chiefs-logo-transparent.png",
                          "Alabama Crimson Tide" = "https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/thumb/1/1b/Alabama_Crimson_Tide_logo.svg/1024px-Alabama_Crimson_Tide_logo.svg.png",
                          "Phoenix Suns" = "https://banner2.cleanpng.com/20180419/lpe/kisspng-phoenix-suns-nba-sacramento-kings-charlotte-hornet-basketball-team-logo-5ad88205c602d4.1820850415241385018111.jpg",
                          "San Francisco 49ers" = "http://assets.stickpng.com/images/580b585b2edbce24c47b2b55.png", 
                          "Colorado Avalanche" = "http://assets.stickpng.com/images/5a4fbb29da2b4f099b95da0b.png", 
                          "Tampa Bay Buccaneers" = "http://assets.stickpng.com/thumbs/580b585b2edbce24c47b2b5e.png", 
                          "Washington Capitals" = "http://assets.stickpng.com/images/5a4fbbeada2b4f099b95da22.png",
                          "Philadelphia Eagles" = "http://assets.stickpng.com/thumbs/580b585b2edbce24c47b2b4b.png",
                          "Georgia Bulldogs" = "https://flyclipart.com/thumb2/logo-university-of-georgia-bulldogs-bulldog-head-585520.png",
                          "Chicago Bears" = "https://cdn.freebiesupply.com/images/large/2x/chicago-bears-logo-transparent.png", 
                          "Cincinnati Bengals" = "http://assets.stickpng.com/images/580b585b2edbce24c47b2b19.png", 
                          "New Orleans Saints" = "https://cdn.freebiesupply.com/images/large/2x/new-orleans-saints-logo-transparent.png",
                          "Baltimore Ravens" = "https://cdn.freebiesupply.com/images/large/2x/baltimore-ravens-logo-transparent.png",
                          "Minnesota Wild" = "http://assets.stickpng.com/images/5a4fbb61da2b4f099b95da12.png",
                          "Vegas Golden Knights" = "http://assets.stickpng.com/images/5a4fbbe1da2b4f099b95da21.png",
                          "Buffalo Bills" = "https://cdn.freebiesupply.com/images/large/2x/buffalo-bills-logo-transparent.png",
                          "Pittsburgh Steelers" = "http://assets.stickpng.com/images/580b585b2edbce24c47b2b4e.png",
                          "Tennessee Titans" = "http://assets.stickpng.com/images/580b585b2edbce24c47b2b61.png",
                          "Dallas Cowboys"= 'https://cdn.freebiesupply.com/images/large/2x/dallas-cowboys-logo-transparent.png',
                          "Seattle Seahawks" = "https://cdn.freebiesupply.com/images/large/2x/seattle-seahawks-logo-transparent.png",
                          "Green Bay Packers" = "http://assets.stickpng.com/images/580b585b2edbce24c47b2b25.png",
                          "West Virginia Mountaineers" = "https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/thumb/e/e8/West_Virginia_Mountaineers_logo.svg/1987px-West_Virginia_Mountaineers_logo.svg.png",
                          "Arkansas Razorbacks" = "https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/e/ef/Arkansas-Razorback-Logo-2001.png",
                          "La Rams" = "http://assets.stickpng.com/images/608968b9d598a5000448eaa2.png",
                          "Washington Commanders" = "https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/thumb/0/0c/Washington_Commanders_logo.svg/2560px-Washington_Commanders_logo.svg.png",
                          "Philadelphia 76ers" = "http://assets.stickpng.com/images/58419ca3a6515b1e0ad75a64.png",
                          "Charlotte Fc" = "https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/en/thumb/9/91/Charlotte_FC_logo.svg/1200px-Charlotte_FC_logo.svg.png",
                          "Nebraska Cornhuskers" = "https://cdn.freebiesupply.com/logos/large/2x/nebraska-corn-huskers-logo-png-transparent.png",
                          "New York Yankees" = "http://assets.stickpng.com/images/584d4b740a44bd1070d5d494.png",
                          "Oklahoma Sooners" = "https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/4/49/Oklahoma_Sooners_logo.png",
                          "Milwaukee Brewers" = "https://purepng.com/public/uploads/large/milwaukee-brewers-logo-9xg.png",
                          "Los Angeles Dodgers" = "http://assets.stickpng.com/images/584d3e8a0a44bd1070d5d3d7.png",
                          "Denver Broncos" = "https://cdn.freebiesupply.com/images/large/2x/denver-broncos-logo-transparent.png",
                          "Washington Nationals" = "https://cdn.freebiesupply.com/images/large/2x/washington-nationals-logo-transparent.png",
                          "Philadelphia Phillies" = "http://assets.stickpng.com/images/584d42ac0a44bd1070d5d420.png",
                          "Atlanta Braves" = "https://1000logos.net/wp-content/uploads/2017/08/Atlanta-Braves-logo.png",
                          "Iowa Hawkeyes" = "https://1000logos.net/wp-content/uploads/2021/06/Iowa-Hawkeyes-logo.png",
                          "Gonzaga University Bulldogs" = "https://www.pngkey.com/png/full/65-655460_bulldog-700x441-gonzaga-bulldog.png",
                          "Chicago Cubs" = "http://assets.stickpng.com/images/584d41b10a44bd1070d5d411.png",
                          "Kentucky Wildcats" = "https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/5/5d/Kentucky_Wildcats_logo_2015.png",
                          "Lsu Tigers" = "https://www.nicepng.com/png/full/96-961386_lsu-football-png-transparent-lsu-football-louisiana-state.png",
                          "Boston Red Sox"= "https://cdn.freebiesupply.com/images/large/2x/boston-red-sox-logo-transparent.png",
                          "Detroit Tigers" = "https://cdn.freebiesupply.com/images/large/2x/detroit-tigers-logo-transparent.png",
                          "Minnesota Twins" = "http://assets.stickpng.com/images/584d47ae0a44bd1070d5d45d.png",
                          "St Louis Cardinals" = "http://assets.stickpng.com/images/584d3fc80a44bd1070d5d3ed.png",
                          "Mississippi State Bulldogs" = "https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/thumb/3/36/Mississippi_State_Bulldogs_logo.svg/640px-Mississippi_State_Bulldogs_logo.svg.png",
                          "Cleveland Browns" = "https://cdn.freebiesupply.com/images/large/2x/cleveland-browns-logo-transparent.png",
                          "Portland Trailblazers" = "https://cdn.freebiesupply.com/images/large/2x/portland-trail-blazers-logo-transparent.png",
                          "Masters" = "https://logos-world.net/wp-content/uploads/2022/02/Masters-Symbol.png",
                          "Tennessee Vols" = "https://1000logos.net/wp-content/uploads/2021/07/Tennessee-Volunteers-logo.png",
                          "Houston Astros"= "http://assets.stickpng.com/images/584d493b0a44bd1070d5d477.png",
                          "Utah Jazz" = "http://assets.stickpng.com/images/58419bb6a6515b1e0ad75a55.png",
                          "La Lakers" = "http://assets.stickpng.com/images/58419d0aa6515b1e0ad75a6c.png",
                          "Kansas Jayhawks" = "https://brandslogos.com/wp-content/uploads/images/large/kansas-jayhawks-logo.png",
                          "Baltimore Orioles" = "https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/en/thumb/7/75/Baltimore_Orioles_cap.svg/1200px-Baltimore_Orioles_cap.svg.png",
                          "Unc Tar Heels" = "https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/thumb/d/d7/North_Carolina_Tar_Heels_logo.svg/512px-North_Carolina_Tar_Heels_logo.svg.png",
                          "South Carolina Gamecocks" = "https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/thumb/9/94/South_Carolina_Gamecocks_logo.svg/933px-South_Carolina_Gamecocks_logo.svg.png",
                          "Seattle Mariners" = "http://assets.stickpng.com/images/584d467c0a44bd1070d5d44c.png",
                          "Colorado Rockies" = "https://www.nicepng.com/png/full/141-1415329_colorado-rockies-logos-png-clipart-download-colorado-rockies.png",
                          "Golden State Warriors" = "http://assets.stickpng.com/images/58419ce2a6515b1e0ad75a69.png",
                          "Chicago White Sox" = "http://assets.stickpng.com/images/584d4aff0a44bd1070d5d48d.png",
                          "Boston Celtics" = "http://assets.stickpng.com/images/58419c6aa6515b1e0ad75a61.png",
                          "Carolina Hurricanes" = "https://toppng.com/uploads/preview/carolina-hurricanes-nhl-logo-png-11536005105kxafnwdw2o.png",
                          "Tampa Bay Lightning" = "http://assets.stickpng.com/images/5a4fbbc8da2b4f099b95da1e.png",
                          "Oregon Ducks" = "https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/thumb/f/f8/Oregon_Ducks_logo.svg/928px-Oregon_Ducks_logo.svg.png",
                          "Milwaukee Bucks" = "http://assets.stickpng.com/images/58419ba7a6515b1e0ad75a54.png",
                          "Los Angeles Angels" = "http://assets.stickpng.com/images/584d498d0a44bd1070d5d47b.png",
                          "Carolina Panthers" = "https://cdn.freebiesupply.com/images/large/2x/carolina-panthers-logo-transparent.png",
                          "Minnesota Vikings" = "http://assets.stickpng.com/images/580b585b2edbce24c47b2b38.png",
                          "New England Patriots" = "http://assets.stickpng.com/images/580b585b2edbce24c47b2b3b.png",
                          "Clemson Tigers" = "https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/thumb/7/72/Clemson_Tigers_logo.svg/1071px-Clemson_Tigers_logo.svg.png",
                          "Wyoming Cowboys" = "https://cdn.freebiesupply.com/logos/large/2x/wyoming-cowboys-logo-png-transparent.png",
                          "Arizona Cardinals" = "https://cdn.freebiesupply.com/images/large/2x/arizona-cardinals-logo-transparent.png",
                          "Washington Football Team" = "http://assets.stickpng.com/images/60896cf3d598a5000448eaa8.png",
                          "Indianapolis Colts" = "http://assets.stickpng.com/images/580b585b2edbce24c47b2b2c.png",
                          "Detroit Lions" = "https://cdn.freebiesupply.com/images/large/2x/detroit-lions-logo-transparent.png",
                          "Las Vegas Raiders" = "https://www.pngmart.com/files/16/Las-Vegas-Raiders-Transparent-Background.png",
                          "Michigan State Spartans" = "http://assets.stickpng.com/images/6103b47a2d29570004bc56f2.png",
                          "Utah Utes" = "http://assets.stickpng.com/images/5859a2df4f6ae202fedf28ec.png",
                          "Seattle Kraken" = "https://www.gannett-cdn.com/presto/2020/07/23/PPAS/b671207b-9fd0-46ea-a78a-f1c0fd3cab7d-Edn6Cc3XgAALN8o.jpg",
                          "Michigan Wolverines" = "https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/3/36/Michigan_Wolverines_Block_M.png"
      ))
    
    for (i in seq_len(nrow(logos))) {
      logo <- logos[i, ]
      shape <- states[states$State == logo$State, ]
      
      img <- rasterpic_img(shape, logo$png, mask = TRUE)
      
      plot <- plot + geom_spatraster_rgb(data = img)
    }
    
    plot
```

Currently, I am receiving this error: Error: [as,sf] coercion failed. You can try coercing via a Spatial* (sp) class.

The goal of this is to have a US map with sports logos on each state. It is most googled sports teams by state. So if the Yankees sell the most in New York, I want the Yankees logo plotted on top of the state. My dataset being used is very, very simple. It is two columns - the state name and the team name. (i.e. Column A (ShipState) is AL, Column B (Team) is Alabama Crimson Tide.) For some reason, the loop is failing. Can anyone tell me what may be going wrong?

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried storing images locally instead of sourcing them from the internet? The thing is if any of the website goes down, the image wont appear.

Furthermore, to embed image src code is required. for example:

```
<img src="https://s1.pngtank.com/thumbnails/63c1c0b584396.png">
```

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).